# recvfrom only read 15 bytes

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I have trouble to read more than 15 bytes with recvfrom , i have tried to change the SO_RCVBUF option and increasing the size of the recvfrom argument but still only read 15 bytes.

```
int a = 65535;
if (setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &a, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting socket opts: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}  
...
bytes = recvfrom(sd, buffer, 2048, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addr_len);
```

but the recvfrom function still read only 15 bytes.

clientUDP.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char ** argv){

    int sd, addr_len, bytes;
    char buffer[2048];
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    sd = socket ( PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    bzero (&addr, sizeof (addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(8787);
    inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr );
    printf("->:");
    gets(buffer);
    sendto (sd, buffer , 15, 0 ,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    do{
        addr_len = sizeof(addr);
      setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &a, sizeof(int));

        bytes = recvfrom(sd, buffer, 2048, MSG_WAITALL,,(struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addr_len);
        if(bytes>0){
                printf("Mensaje de %s: %d (%d bytes)\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port), bytes );

                printf("el mensaje dice :"); 
                puts(buffer);
                printf("-:");
                gets(buffer);
                sendto (sd, buffer , 15, 0 ,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

         }

    }while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

serverUDP.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main (int argc, char ** argv){

  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  int sd;
  int bytes, reply_len, addr_len;
  char buffer[2048];
  sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
  int a = 65535;

  bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(8787);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  if(bind(sd,(struct sockaddr *)  &addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0){
    printf("Error en BIND\n");
  }
  do {
      addr_len = sizeof(addr);

      bytes = recvfrom(sd, buffer, 2048, MSG_WAITALL,(struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addr_len);
      setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &a, sizeof(int));
      if(bytes>0){
    printf("Mensaje de %s: %d (%d bytes)\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port), bytes );
    printf("el mensaje dice :"); 
    puts(buffer);
    printf("-:");
    gets(buffer);
        sendto (sd, buffer , 15, 0 ,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

      }
  }while(1);
}
```

Comment: May sound like a stupid question, but are you sure you are actually supposed to receive more? What does wireshark say about the packets?

Comment: Have you tried adding `MSG_WAITALL` to the flags?

Comment: Its a string obtained with gets , i have added       bytes = recvfrom(sd, buffer, 2048, MSG_WAITALL,(struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addr_len); but is the same, its like a chat app

Comment: how is the data on the other end sent? u sure its not sent "byte by byte"?

Comment: my mistake, i put 15 in sendto fuction length look the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UDP is message based, unlike TCP which is stream based.  `recv/from()` cannot receive partial UDP data, reads are all-or-nothing.  If you pass in a 2048-byte buffer and `recv/from()` reports that 15 bytes were read, then the UDP message payload really was 15 bytes in size.  You can use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to verify that.

Comment: It's not entirley all or nothing, if you pass in a buffer size less than the actual packet, you get a truncated packet

Answer (score 1):

Was my mystake i don't know why i put 15 in the sendto function, so only 15bytes of data was sended...XD

```
    sendto (sd, buffer , 15, 0 ,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

solved increasing 15 to 2048